How come the tag excerpt doesn't match what's in the wiki?
I was scanning through tags and noticed that the excerpt for protocol says "transfer cryptocurrencies" which is just horrible.  But when I clicked in to edit it I found "Questions relating to the protocols used to transfer crypto-currencies" as the actual excerpt, which is perfectly appropriate.  What's the deal here?  Is this an edit that hasn't been approved, or are excerpts just wonky here?

Maybe it was recently updated? Here it seems to be fine.

By "here it seems to be fine" do you mean that when you go to this list the excerpt is something other than "transfer cryptocurrencies" for the [tag:protocol] tag?  Because that's still what I'm seeing.

Sorry, you are correct. I was talking about the tooltip shown when you hover your mouse over the tag or when you type "protocol" in a question inside the tags section. These are both correct. Inside the tags list the excerpt is wrong.

Still hasn't changed. Seems like an SE bug.

okay, I'm going to cross-post to meta.so

Okay, a search on meta.so revealed this question, which points out the existence of a script that tries to automagically remove unnecessary text from a tag excerpt.  In this case, apparently, the script was detecting the phrase ending in "...used to transfer cryptocurrencies" and assuming everything before "used to" was simply a description of the tag.  I've rephrased the excerpt to avoid this pitfall, and as soon as the edit is approved it should show the correct excerpt (assuming I don't trigger a new form of script-magic).

Done. Problem solved.

The protocol excerpt was last updated on Sep. 6.. The revision show that it never stated "transfer cryptocurrencies" which is very odd. I have made a minor change to the tag excerpt, maybe it fixes also the description on the "tags" page. 

Just approved your edit, but it stayed the same :-(
